# What methods exist to expose documentation on SOAP interfaces?

Tags: java, soap, documentation, wsdl

I am attempting to expose documentation (like Javadocs) for a SOAP Service. Best case, it would either be exposed directly from the WSDL or through an autonomously generated report. I am using CXF as my SOAP implementation.

I have tried using the WSDL Viewer found [here](http://tomi.vanek.sk/index.php?page=wsdl-viewer), but I havn't found a good tutorial on how to annotate my methods to get the structure and level of detail seen in his example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I’ve found thus far is to use an engine known as Enunciate (http://enunciate.codehaus.org/). Once added to the project it reads the JavaDocs and composes a set of HTML files. I don't fully understand all of the features or problems (it generates and links to its own WSDL, which isn't ideal, and does "scratch work" within an extra folder in the project which then reads as an error unless deleted), but it does successfully read and expose the JavaDocs in a clear and useable manner.